# Belgium visa needed for travel or not

Tags: international-travel, belgium

I lost my passport while on holiday in India and I am holding a Belgian resident permit. Since I applied for a new passport, is it ok travel back to Belgium without a visa by holding a Belgium resident permit?

Comment: Did your lost passport contain any valid Belgian (or other Schengen) visa or other endorsement?  If so, you should report its loss to the consulate in India.  They will be able to tell you how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

You can enter Belgium (or any other country in the Schengen area) with an EU format residence card (something that [looks like that](http://prado.consilium.europa.eu/en/3598/viewImage_85936.html)). It's part of the Schengen regulations (article 5 of the Schengen borders code) and I have some friends who have done it successfully.

You do need a valid passport as well (i.e. you will need your new passport, even if it has no visa) and you might expect some confusion when checking in (one friend once had to wait for confused check-in personnel to call a supervisor to check her documents but she did ultimately manage to board the flight).